# Cannot update array in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

I am trying to change the state of an item in the array. I did what you commented on the previous answer but when I console.log the array I am updating it grows in number! This is the code

```
changeState = (i) => {
  console.log(this.state.selected)
  const array = [...this.state.selected];

  if (this.state.selected[i] === true) {
    array[i] = false
  } else {
    array[i] = true
  }

  this.setState({
    selected: array
  })

  console.log(array[i])
}
```

When I run the screen I create the selected array with all values in false, then when pressing the button, it sends the index using "i" and then the array instead of changing from true to false or viceversa, the array only increases in size

Comment: can you create a js fiddle or some demo ?

Comment: This all depends on what `i` is. It's probably >= `this.state.selected.length`

Answer (score 0):

This is a clone of your array.  You can't update it's values.

```
const array = [...this.state.selected];
```

Answer (score 0):

Code looks okay. Please notice that in JavaScript you are allowed to assign a value in an undefined index that currently is out of bounds of an array. 
For instance:

```
var arr=[];
arr[2]="value";
// arr = [undefined,undefined,"value"];
// arr.length = 3
```

So the only thing i can think about is that `changeState` gets the wrong index (maybe an index that greater than the array in your state)